# Tell whether net.Listener is dead

Tags: networking, go, error-handling

In Go, a call to the [`net.Listener`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Listener) type's `Accept` method returns an error. However, is there a way to tell the difference between a transient error (ie, this connection failed to set up) vs a permanent error (ie, the listener is dead, such as a Unix domain socket file that was forcibly removed)? If I can't tell the difference, I run the risk of infinite looping and spitting out errors as fast as I can since each `Accept` call will immediately return an error.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. Errors returned by the `net` package may be of the [`net.Error`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Error) type, which defines the `Temporary() bool` method which reports whether the error is temporary.